# GoLang Pointer Performance

Tags: performance, memory, go, stack, benchmarking

The following code shows two benchmarks. The first one creates a struct by value in each iteration, while the second one does use a pointer to the struct.

Why is the latter 20x slower ?? I know about GC issues with GoLang, but shouldn't escape analysis handle those situations ?

I'm using go1.4beta1, but 1.3.3 gave me the [same - wrong] *different* results.

Any idea ?

```
package main

import "testing"

type Adder struct {
    vals []int
}

func (a *Adder) add() int {
    return a.vals[0] + a.vals[1]
}

func BenchmarkWithoutPointer(b *testing.B) {
    accum := 0
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        adder := Adder{[]int{accum, i}}
        accum = adder.add()
    }
    _ = accum
}

func BenchmarkWithPointer(b *testing.B) {
    accum := 0
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        adder := &Adder{[]int{accum, i}}
        accum = adder.add()
    }
    _ = accum
}
```

Benchmark go1.4.1:

```
 $ go test -bench=.                                                                                                                             

testing: warning: no tests to run
PASS
BenchmarkWithoutPointer 1000000000           2.92 ns/op
BenchmarkWithPointer    30000000            57.8 ns/op
ok      github.com/XXXXXXXXXX/bench/perf    5.010s
```

Benchmark go1.3.3:

```
testing: warning: no tests to run
PASS
BenchmarkWithoutPointer 500000000            7.89 ns/op
BenchmarkWithPointer    50000000            37.5 ns/op
ok
```

EDIT:

Conclusion:

As Ainar-G said, the []int does escape to heap in the second benchmark. After reading a bit more about 1.4beta1 it seems, that new write barriers are introduced when accessing the heap caused by the new GC plans. But raw execution seems to have increased. Looking forward to 1.5 =).

Comment: What machine code is generated for the two?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/chrisprobst/4c0231c24e1fc4a215cd

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Running the benchmark with the `-m` gcflag gives the possible answer:

```
./main_test.go:16: BenchmarkWithoutPointer []int literal does not escape
(...)
./main_test.go:25: []int literal escapes to heap
```

Your `[]int` in the second example escapes to heap, which is slower than stack. If you use separate `x` and `y` fields for your arguments instead of a slice

```
type Adder struct {
    x, y int
}

func (a *Adder) add() int {
    return a.x + a.y
}
```

the benchmark shows the expected behaviour:

```
BenchmarkWithoutPointer 1000000000               2.27 ns/op
BenchmarkWithPointer    2000000000               1.98 ns/op
```

Comment: I see, I just looked into the machine code. The second function contains a  "0x00d8 00216 (bench_test.go:25) CALL ,runtime.writebarrierslice(SB)" call. Do you know why the int slice is considered escaping ? In my opinion, it is not really "escaping".

Comment: @Kr0e There are [issues](https://code.google.com/p/go/issues/list?q=escape+analysis) with the escape analysis. They are known and some are scheduled to be fixed in 1.5. Until then, *if your code is very performance-sensitive,* use benchmarks, `-gcflags '-m'`, or try a different compiler.

Comment: Alright, thanks mate! The example was trivial anyway, of course using two integers makes more sense in this case. I just want to understand how go works (currently) =). FYI: I did a mistake, 1.3.3 has different performance characteristics. The results are not better, just different.

Answer (score 2):

running the exact code from the original post with go1.16.7 the pointer version is now about the same speed (slightly faster)

```
$ go test -bench=.
goos: linux
goarch: amd64
pkg: example.com/x
cpu: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-9850H CPU @ 2.60GHz
BenchmarkWithoutPointer-12      945450447            1.212 ns/op
BenchmarkWithPointer-12         965921562            1.199 ns/op
PASS
ok      example.com/x   2.562s
```

so the compiler has gotten smarter since OP posed his question :)